# Keep instant search results hover open to edit with Chrome tools

Tags: algolia

We are trying to customize the Algoila instant results hover menu to fit our custom Magento theme. Does anyone know of a way to keep the instant result menu open so we can inspect elements using Chrome tools?

Answer (score 7):

You can put [the following](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/blob/60afa15bfbca30b7acde0fd99423287668bdc72a/design/frontend/template/topsearch.phtml#L764) `debug` flag to `true`:

```
  var options = {
      hint: false,
      templates: {
          dropdownMenu: '#menu-template'
      },
      dropdownMenuContainer: "#algolia-autocomplete-container",
      debug: true // to inspect the dropdown menu
  };
```

The associated documentation is [here](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#options).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, open Chrome developer tools, go to the 'source' tab and from there you can click `Cmd + \` to pause the script whilst the dropdown is visible.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for elements state on the right side of the development tools:

[image: See Screen capture]